# Floating Point Addition in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm having trouble with Floating Point Addition in C.

We're given two 16 bit numbers, we're supposed to add them not worrying about cases where their signs are different or where the exponents are 0 or 31.
This is a homework assignment, but I'm late & I can't figure out why it's not working.

The Algrothim sort of looks like:

1. Get the sign bits of each number, if their different return 0.
2. Get the exponents of each number, find the bigger one
   2a. find out the difference between the two.
3. in the 11th bit put in a implicit one into each of the mantissa's
4. Right shift the number with the smaller exponent by the difference of the exponents
5. Take the sign and exponent of the larger number or it with the shifted mantissa.
6. Return the result.

Here's my code:

```
LC3_Word FLADD(LC3_Word A, LC3_Word B)
{
    // a debug variable, so we can turn errors on (debug = 1) and off (debug = 0)
    int debug = 1; 

    // a default return value 
    LC3_Word returnValue = 0x0000;

    if(debug)
    {
        printf("-----------------------------------\nBegin debug\n-----------------------------------\n");
        printf("Return value: %x \n",returnValue); 
        printf("LC3 words: A %x, B %x\n",A,B);
    }

    // Masks to extract sign, exponent and fraction 
    LC3_Word signBitMask = 0x8000; 
    LC3_Word expMask = 0x7C000; 
    LC3_Word mantissaMask = 0x03FF; 

    // Mask to get the sign with the exponent
    LC3_Word signExpMask = 0xFC00;

    // A mask for the implicit 1
    LC3_Word implicitOne = 0x0400; 

    // Getting the signs
    LC3_Word signA = AND(signBitMask,A); 
    LC3_Word signB = AND(signBitMask,B);

    // Getting the exponents 
    LC3_Word expA = AND(expMask,A); 
    LC3_Word expB = AND(expMask,B); 

    // Getting the mantissa's 
    LC3_Word mantA = AND(mantissaMask,A);
    LC3_Word mantB = AND(mantissaMask,B);

        if(debug)
        {
            printf("======================\n");
            printf("\tSignBitMask: %x\n\texpMask: %x\n\tmantissaMask: %x\n",signBitMask,expMask,mantissaMask);
            printf("\tSign EXP Mask: %x\n",signExpMask);
            printf("\tsignA: %x, signB: %x\n", signA, signB); 
            printf("\tImplicit One Mask: %x\n",implicitOne); 
            printf("\tExp of a: %x, Exp of b: %x\n", expA, expB); 
            printf("\tmantissa of A: %x,mantissa of B: %x\n",mantA,mantB);
            printf("======================\n");
        }

    // Getting each with it's sign bit and it's exponent 
    LC3_Word signExpA = AND(signExpMask,A); 
    LC3_Word signExpB = AND(signExpMask,B); 

        if(debug)
        {
            printf("signExpA of A: %i, signExpB of B: %i\n",signExpA,signExpB);
        }

    // if the signs are different, don't deal with this case 
    if(signA!=signB)
    {
        return 0; 
    }   

    // if the signs are the same, if not, just return the default value 
    if(signA==signB)
    {
        if(debug)
        {
            printf("We got into the if signs are the same block \n");
            printf("Sign a: %i, Sign b: %i \n",signA,signB); 
        }

        if(expA==expB)
        {
            if(debug)
            {
                printf("We got into the if exponents are the same block \n");
                printf("Exp a: %x, Exp b: %x \n",expA,expB); 
            }

            // exponents are the same
            // Add Mantissa B to A 
            mantA = ADD(mantB,mantA);
            if(debug)
            {
                printf("Addition of mantissa's %x\n",mantA); 
            }
            // store into the return value the logical and of the mantissa with the existing exponent and sign
            // might want to do an OR() not an AND()
            returnValue = OR(signExpA,mantA); 
        } // end if the eponents are the same 
        else {
            if(debug)
            {
                printf("The exponents are not the same block \n");
            }
            // Getting the size we need to shift by
            int sizeToShift = 0; 
            if(expA>expB)
            {
                // Mask the mantissa of B with a implicit 1, then right shift
                mantB = OR(implicitOne,mantB); 

                if(debug)
                {
                    printf("The exponent a is > b\n");
                }
                // need to shift B, getting the size of how much
                sizeToShift = expA-expB;

                if(debug)
                {
                    printf("size to shift: %d,\nmantissaB is: %x\n",sizeToShift,mantB); 
                }
                // right shifting the mantissa of b
                mantB = mantB >> sizeToShift; 

                if(debug)
                {
                    printf("mantissa of b shifted: %x\n",mantB);
                }
                returnValue = OR(signExpA,ADD(mantA,mantB));
            }// end if A > B in the exponent 
            else
            {
                // Mask the mantissa of A with a implicit 1, then right shift
                mantA = OR(implicitOne,mantA);
                if(debug)
                {
                    printf("The exponent B is > A\n");
                }
                // need to shift A, getting the size of how much
                sizeToShift = expB-expA;

                if(debug)
                {
                    printf("size to shift: %d,\nmantissaA is: %x\n",sizeToShift,mantA); 
                }
                // right shifting the mantissa of A
                mantA = mantA >> sizeToShift; 

                if(debug)
                {
                    printf("mantissa of A shifted: %x\n",mantA);
                }
                returnValue = OR(signExpB,ADD(mantA,mantB));
            }// end if B > A in the exponent        
        }// end if different exponents 
    } // end if the signs are the same

    if(debug)
    {
        printf("Return Value %x\n",returnValue);
        printf("-----------------------------------\nEnd debug\n-----------------------------------\n");
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Here are ADD, OR and AND,

```
LC3_Word AND(LC3_Word A, LC3_Word B)
{
    return (A&B);
}

LC3_Word OR(LC3_Word A, LC3_Word B)
{
    return (A|B);
}

LC3_Word ADD(LC3_Word A, LC3_Word B)
{
    return (A+B); 
}
```

When I add 2 + 3 in floating point I get 3 instead of 5.

Any ideas?

Comment: These are 16-bit floating point values?  If so, don't you have too many zeros on your expMask?

Comment: After a very brief look it looks like you aren't accounting for the implicit "1" in the simple path where exponents are equal.

Comment: You shouldn't use a seperate variable for debugging like that. It may comsume memory and/or CPU. And what if there are hundreds of those variables at different places? Do you intent to edit them all? Use `#define` and `#ifdef` instead, they will be managed by preprocessor and strip out if needed as they've never existed in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if(expA==expB)
    {
        if(debug)
        {
            printf("We got into the if exponents are the same block \n");
            printf("Exp a: %x, Exp b: %x \n",expA,expB); 
        }

        // exponents are the same
        // Add Mantissa B to A 
        mantA = ADD(mantB,mantA);
        if(debug)
        {
            printf("Addition of mantissa's %x\n",mantA); 
        }
        // store into the return value the logical and of the mantissa with the existing exponent and sign
        // might want to do an OR() not an AND()
        returnValue = OR(signExpA,mantA); 
    } // end if the eponents are the same
```

This is wrong.

You're failing to account for the addition of the two implicit ones. When you're adding 2 + 3 you're adding 1.0 x 2^1 + 1.1 x 2^1 and you're ignoring everything before the decimal point... So you end up with 0.0 + 0.1 = 0.1 and just stick a 1 at the front. You need to add the two implicit ones as well.

Try something like this:

```
    if(expA==expB)
    {
        if(debug)
        {
            printf("We got into the if exponents are the same block \n");
            printf("Exp a: %x, Exp b: %x \n",expA,expB); 
        }

        // exponents are the same
        // Add Mantissa B to A 
        mantA = OR(implicitOne,mantA);
        mantB = OR(implicitOne,mantB);

        mantA = ADD(mantB,mantA);

        // You need to normalize this now. But shifting to the right by 1 will suffice.
        mantA >>= 1;
        ++expA;
        // ... add the sign and you're done...

        if(debug)
        {
            printf("Addition of mantissa's %x\n",mantA); 
        }
        // store into the return value the logical and of the mantissa with the existing exponent and sign
        // might want to do an OR() not an AND()
        returnValue = OR(signExpA,mantA); 
    } // end if the eponents are the same
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still reading through the code but shouldn't

LC3_Word expMask = 0x7C000;

be

LC3_Word expMask = 0x7C00;?

Also, can you paste binary representations of your numbers? Just so we are clear on what is being put through this algorithm. The bug could also be in your conversion code if you are using one...